# Unable to call graph API from SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to call the graph API for fetching user profile information.

The blog post I followed is:

[Extending SharePoint with ADAL and the Microsoft Graph API](http://julieturner.net/2017/01/extending-sharepoint-with-adal-and-the-microsoft-graph-api-part-1-the-setup/)

**My AAD app config is like:**

1. URL: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com`
2. Reply-url: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com`

Permissions: Graph API :: Read all users' full profiles

However, I am getting an error of invalid reply url. Not sure what reply url is it trying to send the response to.

Comment: can you share your entire error? with Error message and error code?

Comment: Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://ajcontoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ajsite/SiteAssets/ADALTest.html' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'. More details: not specified

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working. So basically, all the steps mentioned in the blog were applied and they are correct. However, for me I had to set the reply URL to the page from which I was calling the code instead of the tenant url or site collection url.

My reply-url had to be set as:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SiteAssets/ADAPTest.aspx
```

and I started receiving the token which was then passed to the grpah API to fetch information.

Comment: Hi Ashish, When you say reply-url what do you exactly mean?